# Using ggplot with the AirPassengers Dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to graph the trend of AirPassengers and the "raw data" with ggplot but I am not able to get the data to play nicely with ggplot. I'm not looking for someone to do the problem for me but I am in need of advice as I have hit a wall.

code :

```r
# how I am given the data set to work with 
AirPassengers <- as.data.frame(AirPassengers)

# trying to get the data with a yearly trend
AP <- ts(AirPassengers, start = c(1949,1), frequency = 12) # doesn't work with freq = 1
dAP <- decompose(AP, type = "multiplicative")
dAP_trend <- dAP$trend
```

AirPassengers AP, and dAP (From the code above) don't work with ggplot. However, I was able to get the plots of the trend and the "raw data" painlessly with plot and using :

```r
plot(AirPassengers)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(dAP_trend, type="l", col="green" )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By `zoo::as.zoo` and `time()`

```
autoplot(as.zoo(AP), geom = "line") +
  geom_line(aes(x = time(dAP_trend), y = dAP_trend), color = "green")
```

[image: ts]

Comment: Thank you! It is giving a much better graph like this, there is a warning
Warning: Removed 12 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).
but I will try to figure out.

Comment: @cml99 If you mean `Removed 12 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).`, it's because of `NA` produced by trend of `decompose` is by moving average,

Comment: I see, is AP setup as a time series with yearly trend using 
`AP <- ts(AirPassengers, start = c(1949,1), frequency = 12)`?

Comment: @cml99 Every objects in my code are based on your code. `AP` is ts object with frequency 12.